# Why is Wordpress get_the_ID() returning empty?

Tags: php, wordpress

My code is simple:

```
$group_id = get_the_ID();
if ( get_post_meta ($group_id, '_um_groups_shells', true) == 'true'){
    wp_set_object_terms( $group_id, array( 'full-shells' ), 'um_group_categories', true );
} elseif ( get_post_meta ($group_id, '_um_groups_shells', true) == 'false'){
    wp_remove_object_terms( $group_id, array( 'full-shells' ), 'um_group_categories', true );
}
```

I have checked that the conditionals are working correctly by using `die("Group:". $group_id);`

What I discovered is that in the example `die("Group:". $group_id);` the `$group_id` returns `51478`.  But if I use just `die($group_id);` then it is empty.

Based on that, I'm assuming that

```
wp_set_object_terms( $group_id, array( 'full-shells' ), 'um_group_categories', true );
```

doesn't work because `$group_id` must be empty.

If I run it like this:

```
$group_id = 51478;
wp_set_object_terms( $group_id, array( 'full-shells' ), 'um_group_categories', true );
```

then it works fine.

**Update**
I tried wpdevloper_j's suggestion of using `global $post; $post->ID;` instead.  But the same problem occurred.  I can `echo $group_id` and `print_r($group_id)` and get the correct id, but when trying to execute with `wp_set_object_terms` it seems to be empty.

What is causing `$group_id` to be empty?

When I do `var_dump ($group_id)`, I receive `int(51478)`

**Updated Solution**
The problem was with a subsequent line of code:

```
wp_set_object_terms( $group_id, $formdata[ 'categories' ], 'um_group_categories', false );
```

The `false` parameter was undoing the previous.  So it was executing and then updating again after the successful execution.

That was so frustrating. :(

Comment: from where u r accessing this code?

Comment: please try global $post;  $post->ID; instead

Comment: @wpdevloper_j It's in a plugin action folder. `plugins/um-groups/includes/actions/um-groups-actions.php`.  I will try the global like you said.

Answer (score 0):

die() — Equivalent to exit

```
exit ( string $status = ? ) : void
exit ( int $status ) : void
```

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.exit.php